# How to identify Economy Light fares, or more generally, the booking class, on Skyscanner?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, flight-search-engines

I am booking [this flight](https://www.skyscanner.ro/transport/d/otp/2019-01-03/buea/ptya/2019-04-16/otp?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&ref=home#details/15116-1901031010--32677-2-11453-1901040940%7C15608-1904161855--32132-1-15116-1904181525)

The second one is served by KLM which if we look on [their website](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/baggage/Baggage_Calculator/index.htm) we can see that for a flight Cartagena - Amsterdam - Bucharest, if it is **Economy Light** the checked-in baggage is not included but it is included for **Economy Standard**.

How can I check which option is shown by skyscanner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's Economy Standard.

In general, Skyscanner biases towards showing the lowest price for any flight/itinerary, so if this weren't an overseas flight (and you were just buying Cartagena - Amsterdam), I'd guess you'd get Economy Light. However, clicking through to the link on eDreams, I see that it says Check-in baggage included, suggesting it's Economy Standard.

Usually, airlines are a lot more generous with their long-distance international flights, given they're the most profitable!

[image: Screenshot of eDreams page]